# add one column (subtraction) to a dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I try to add one column in a dataframe df2  which contains the value 0 `if(df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR']) < 0 else  df2['P_ACT_KW']- df2['P_SOUSCR']`.

```
if (df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR']) <0:
    df2['depassement']=0
else:
    df2['depassement']= (df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR'])
```

I got this error message :

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 if (df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR']) <0:
>         2     df2['depassement']=0
>         3 else:
>         4     df2['depassement']= (df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR'])
>
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
>   in **nonzero**(self)
>       890         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
>       891                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
>   --> 892                          .format(self.**class**.**name**))
>       893 
>       894     **bool** = **nonzero**
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any idea please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df2['depassement'] = df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR']
df2[df2['depassement'] < 0, 'depassement'] = 0
```

This should also work:

```
df2['depassement'] = df2.P_ACT_KW.sub(df2.P_SOUSCR).apply(lambda x: max(x, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
df2['depassement'] = np.where((df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR']) < 0), 0, df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR'])
```

`if` doesn't understand how to compare array like structures hence the error, here we can use `np.where` to compare all rows to produce a mask and where the condition is true set to `0` else perform the subtraction